# setting the request header content-type with POST

Tags: javascript, http, jquery, post, content-type

I am trying to send some JSON data to the server but I keep getting a `415 error: Unsupported Media Type`.  This is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://mywebsite.com?'+"token="+token+"&account="+account+"&version=1.0&method=put",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType: "text/json",
                processData: false,data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
                success: function () {  
                    alert("Thanks!"); 
                }
            })

        }
```

I noticed that in the request header there is no `content-type` listed. So how do I set the content type for the request header?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using POST submission and a URL query string? For that matter, you seem to be setting several options without clear reason, and I suspect they're interfering with each other. You can't use jQuery to control the headers you *receive*.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your url is corrupted, you missed `/` and `?`:

```
url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/?'+"token="+token+"&account="+account+"&version=1.0&method=put",
```

Moreover you shuldn't use global urls (with http), because they are blocked by browser...

```
url: "?token="+token+"&account="+account+"&version=1.0&method=put",
```

Comment: the `/` is not necessary. `example.com?foo=bar` will simply be passing foo=bar to whatever the default document is in the site's document root.

Comment: @Krzysiek sorry I changed out the url so I could put it online, I had it with the `?`.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot post data this way outside url. Try following code

```
 $.getJSON("http://www.yourwebsite.com/PersonCount.aspx?id=" + id + "&dt=" + dt + "&t=" + time + "&callback=?", function(data) {
      ///  Your response from {data}
    });
```